# Не отображается Toast и не закрывается AlertDialog

Tags: android

Ребят, почему при нажатии кнопки не закрывается AlertDialog и не появляется Toast?

```
btnSuccess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Category category = categories.get(position);
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),category.name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            toast.show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

Мне необходимо при нажатии кнопки передать объект во Fragment(именно при нажатии, а не при выборе элемента в spinner, но я не пойму, как сделать)

Comment: Судя по коду ничего и не должно происходить. При нажатии на кнопку вы вешаете слушатель на спиннер. Закрытие и тостер срабатывают только после события спиннера.

Comment: как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки получить объект выбранного item?

Comment: Например `spinner.getSelectedİtemPosition()`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: посмотрите, написал в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял, попробуйте так:

```
 Category category = categories.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),category.name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toast.show();
 dialog.dismiss();
```